# LWC wire methods,custom field fetch etc are failing in 2GMP

Tags: lightning-web-components, managed-package

I am having lots of wire method in LWC components and sample code is like below

```
  @wire(fatchPickListValue, {
        objInfo: { 'sobjectType': 'Case' },
        picklistFieldApi: 'Agency__c'
    })
```

In Case object I am having a picklist field `Agency__c` and fetching its value through wire method. Normally its working fine. But after creating 2GMP all custom fields and custom objects are changed to Namespace__Field__C or Namespace__Object__C. So the above code is failing but if I change the above code to

```
  @wire(fatchPickListValue, {
        objInfo: { 'sobjectType': 'Case' },
        picklistFieldApi: 'OVION__Agency__c'
    })
```

then its working. If like this means then I have to change all over the application which is bad. Actually this is not only the case, we are referring custom fields in lots of places like even for saving record.  Sure I feel it must not be the case with managed package. Can you please help?

One another sample
Not working

```
  if (data) {
      if (data.length > 0) {
        this.programOptions = data.map(row => {
          return {
            label: row.RefValue__c,
            value: row.RefKey__c
          };
        });
```

Working

```
  if (data) {
      if (data.length > 0) {
        this.programOptions = data.map(row => {
          return {
            label: row.OVION__RefValue__c,
            value: row.OVION__RefKey__c
          };
        });
```

PS: OVION is the namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's at least two approaches. One is that you can import the schema elements and ask the runtime to provide you their string API names. (Note: the examples below are from the open source managed package [PMM](https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/PMM)).

```
import MY_OBJECT from "@salesforce/schema/MyObject__c";
const FIELD_SET_NAME = "Field_Set";

// ...

    @wire(getFieldSet, {
        objectName: MY_OBJECT.objectApiName, // Salesforce tells us if it's namespaced.
        fieldSetName: FIELD_SET_NAME,
    })
    wiredFields({ error, data }) {
         // Do stuff.
    }
```

Elsewhere, if you need a string value, you can dynamically get your own namespace at runtime to construct the correct value.

```
import MY_CUSTOM_FIELD from "@salesforce/schema/Contact.My_Field__c";

const prefixNamespace = value => {
    let namespace = MY_CUSTOM_FIELD.fieldApiName.substring(
        0,
        MY_CUSTOM_FIELD.fieldApiName.indexOf("My_Field__c")
    );

    return namespace + value;
};
```

This function imports an arbitrary field from the schema and uses that to introspect the namespace; you can import it elsewhere and apply it:

```
            this[NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl]({
                type: ITEM_PAGE_NAVIGATION_TYPE,
                attributes: {
                    apiName: prefixNamespace(MY_TAB_NAME),
                },
```

Comment: Also, getFieldValue from lightning/uiRecordApi can use the token directly to save on some code.

Comment: @David reed. Thanks. I prefer the second one as we are not using field set in application. We are having nearly 75 LWC components and its going to be time comsuming. :)

Comment: @SFDC-Beginner The example is not field-set specific. It's just one example that happens to involve Field Sets.

Comment: @DavidReed , yeah now I got it . Thanks